# how to change a datetime's object 'date' to another object's 'date'? (python)

Tags: python, date, datetime

I'm trying to give an object a different DATE value

*object_a* has a property that contains a datetime value
I wish to change that value to the DATE value of *object_b* (but keep the original TIME value)

Tried the following code but it doesn't seem to work

```
datetime.date(object_a.datetime_value) = datetime.date(object_b.datetime_value)
```

returns:
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `datetime.xxx` objects are immutable - i.e. you can not change them after they have been created. Immutable objects are in general a *good thing*; so you will have to create a new datetime object with the updated year,month,day values:

```
old_dt = ....
new_dt = datetime.datetime( year = new_year, 
                            month = new_month,
                            day = new_day,
                            hour = old_dt.hour,
                            minute = old_dt.minute,
                            second = old_dt.second,
                            microsecond = old_dt.microsecond,
                            tzinfo = old_dt.tzinfo )
```

Comment: I am glad it worked - how about accepting the answer?

Comment: sorry :) still new here